# Referencing global symbols from shared library loaded with dlopen

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dlopen, dlsym

I have a shared library which I want to access symbols from the main program.  For example:

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void) { puts("bar"); }

extern void foo(void);

int main(void) {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

`foo.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void bar(void);

void foo(void) {
    puts("foo");
    bar();
}
```

I compile and run like:

```
gcc -c -fpic foo.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
gcc -L$(pwd) -o test main.c -lfoo
./test
```

And I get the output I expect:

```
foo
bar
```

However, I must use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` because I want to have control over when the library is loaded.  The changed files are:

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void bar(void) { puts("bar"); }

int main(void) {
    void *handle = dlopen("./libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    void (*foo)(void) = (void(*)(void))dlsym(handle,"foo");
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

`foo.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern void bar(void);

void foo(void) {
    puts("foo");
    bar();
}
```

I instead compile and run with:

```
gcc -c -fpic foo.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
gcc -o test main.c -ldl
./test
```

However, this time I get the output

```
foo
./test: symbol lookup error: ./libfoo.so: undefined symbol: bar
```

How can I reference symbols in the main program from libfoo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the `-rdynamic` option when linking `test`:

```
gcc -o test main.c -ldl -rdynamic
```

From [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> -rdynamic
>       Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of dlopen or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program.